# hg clone: No such file or directory?

Tags: git, mercurial, repository

I'm using the attached link resource to transition my repository from mercurial to git because I don't have permission to sudo on the computer I use:

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-and-Other-Systems-Migrating-to-Git

I'm able to get the hg-fast-export into my directory, but when I attempt to clone the repo to my directory I get an error. the statement is the second command in the "Mercurial" subsection, and the exact command I type into my terminal is

```
    {hg clone <hg clone url> /tmp/hg-repo}
```

I get the following error message in my terminal:

```
-bash: https://brandonsmith_wx@bitbucket.org/vmcd/climate-sensitivity-gcm: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you typing in the literal angle brackets, `a <b>` style, rather than replacing `<b>` with the value for `b`?

Comment: that was the issue. thank you